# Loading a CordovaWebView before Tab containing Fragment is chosen

Tags: android, cordova, android-fragments, android-tabs

Currently I have an application with 3 tabs, and each tab contains a separate fragment. One of the tabs/fragments contains a `CordovaWebView`.

The problem I would like to fix, is the `onCreate` method of my `Fragment` than contains the `CordovaWebView` is not called until the tab is selected the first time. This means I have to wait for all the javascript (and cordova.js) to load before anything appears on screen - which takes almost a full second.

**I have this right now:**

```
public class EurtFragment extends Fragment {
    CordovaWebView webView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        webView = new CordovaWebView(getActivity());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");       
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    return webView;
    }
}
```

**What I would like is some way to load up the `CordovaWebView` before the first time the fragment is shown...** something like this, *but this doesn't work because `getActivity()` is returning null - I assume because the Fragment hasn't been created yet!*

```
public EurtFragment(){
    webView = new CordovaWebView(getActivity());
    //**THIS DOESN'T WORK B/C getActivity() returns null

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    return webView;
}
```

I can't seem to find a whole lot of information on this topic - has any one run in to this before and have a solution?